# ASP.NET Core ApiAuthorizationDbContext not creating table for data model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core. When I created a project with ASP.NET Identity enabled, there was an `ApplicationDbContext` template automatically created for me.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    } 
}
```

Now, I also want `ApplicationDbContext` automatically creates tables for my own data models.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Should I do something like this? But this is not working for me.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Student> students;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
    }
}
```

Or should I create another `DbContext` to work with my own custom data models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't forget to use `{get;set;}`

```
public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

Then you need to run this line into your `package manager console`

```
add-migration addStudentsTable
```

It will create this migration for you

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Students",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Students", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Students");
        }
```

Then run this line also to update the database

```
update-database
```

Comment: Thanks, so every time when i update data models, i will need to run migration?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, exactly.